# derivative of mathematical expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value, differences, differential-equations

As we know,if x is a random variable, we could write mathematical expectation based on cumulative distribution function $(F)$ as follow:
$E(X)=\int[1-F(x)]d(x) $

In my problem, t is a random variable that follows a probability distribution function (PDF). I have the mathematical expectation of a function $p(t)$ and i want to write it based on cumulative distribution function $(F)$. Which one of the following equations are correct?

$E(p(t))=\int[1-F(p(t))]d(p(t)) $ or $E(p(t))=\int[1-F(p(t))]d(t) $?

Now I want to differentiate the mathematical expectation based on $t$.

Would you tell me what the first and second derivative will be based on t?

$\frac{dE(p(t))}{dt}=?$ and $\frac{d^2E(p(t))}{dt^2}=?$

Comment: Note that your formula for expectation only works for $x \geq 0$; to see this, consider $x \in (-2,-1)$, for which the expectation is negative, but $1-F(x)$ is always nonnegative, so $E(X)$ as calculated by your expression will be nonnegative.

Comment: What is the definition of a derivative with respect to a random variable?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando

Answer (score 0):

It should be the second one, see here for Definition 1 and second point: https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/teaching/files/Expectation.pdf

First derivative of expectation and similarly can be applied to the second derivative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217702/when-can-we-interchange-the-derivative-with-an-expectation

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it would be better if you included the rationale (applying basic rules of calculus) in your answer; as it is, this is a link-only answer (especially the first part) and, over time, links break, which would render this answer useless.